# Puzzle for Simba to determine the fewest possible exchanges in which this can be done

Tags: group-theory, permutations, puzzle

The field is divided into $25$ squares, with numbers written on each square as shown
in the figure.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
5  & 3  & 17 & 18 & 12 \\ \hline
9  & 13 & 1  & 25 & 23 \\ \hline
6  & 19 & 20 & 2  & 21 \\ \hline
16 & 14 & 15 & 8  & 7  \\ \hline
4  & 24 & 10 & 22 & 11 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Mufasa thinks that it is a good puzzle for Simba to put them all into
regular order so that the first line reads $$1 \text{ }2 \text{ }3 \text{ }4 \text{ }5$$ and the second line reads $$6\text{ } 7\text{ } 8 \text{ }9
\text{ }10$$ and so on to the end, by taking up one counter in each hand and making them
change places. Thus, Simba might take up $7$ and $1$ and replace them as $1$ and $7$.
Then take up $24$ and $2$ and make them also change places, then Simba will have the
first two counters properly placed.

**The puzzle is for Simba to determine the fewest
possible exchanges in which this can be done.**

**What I did**

- The table shown above can be written as the element $$p=(5\text{ }3\text{ }17\text{ }18\text{ }12\text{ }9\text{ }13 \dots 22\text{ }11)$$ of $S_{25}.$
- When we are exchanging two elements, it corresponds to the process of multiplication by a transposition of the form $(a\text{ }b)$ in $S_{25}.$
- So the question reduces to compute the number of transpositions we
  need to multiply $p$ to obtain $q=(1\text{ }2\text{ }3\text{ }4\text{
     }5\text{ }6\text{ }7 \dots 24\text{ }25)$
- So I computed $p^{-1} q$ and it turns out to be product of $3$ cycles
  of length $16,8$ and $1$. Hence I think the minimum number of
  exchanges we need to do is $15+7=22$. But this is **not** the correct
  answer

Where is the fault in my reasoning? and how can I solve this?

Comment: How does swapping one and seven put anything in the right place?

Comment: Its just an example. We need to perform multiple number of swaps to achieve what we want

Comment: It's an example of a swap, but how do the two swaps you mentioned put anything in the right place? Anyway, I'd say the given array corresponds to the permutation, in cycle notation, $(1\ 8\ 19\ 12\ 5)(2\ 14\ 17\ 3)(4\ 21\ 15\ 18)(6\ 11\ 25\ 9)(7\ 20\ 13)(10\ 23)(16)(22\ 24)$, a product of $17$ transpositions.

Comment: $17$ is the correct answer, but I am not sure about your notation. I cannot understand how you got it.

Comment: The $1$ is where the $8$ should be. The $8$ is where the $19$ should be. The $19$ is where the $12$ should be. The $12$ is where the $5$ should be. And the $5$ is where the $1$ should be. That explains the cycle $(1\ 8\ 19\ 12\ 5)$. Similarly for the other cycles.

Comment: Understood, zero2?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is nonresponsive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I got it. Thank you

Comment: OK. Let me encourage you to write up what you found, and post it as an answer.

Comment: okay, I will post an answer after a while